How to set up HasManyThrough relationship with foreign keys only in the intermediate table?
I'm working on a project using Laravel v9.19 and PHP 8.0.
Here is a part of that project's database which is relevant to the question:


One user can have many orders, but each order has only one user (one-to-many relationship).
One order can have only one item, but one item may be present in many orders (many-to-one relationship).

Here is a User class:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get orders of this user.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function orders(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'client_id');
    }
}

Here is an Order class:
class Order extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the client of this order.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function client(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'client_id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the ordered item.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function item(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_id');
    }
}

Here is an Item class:
class Downloadable extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get the orders having this item.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function orders(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'item_id');
    }
}

I would like to utilize the Eloquent Relationships in order to make it possible to:

Retrieve all items ordered by a specific user.
Retrieve all users that ordered a specific item.

I will need to add a new method to the User model:
    /**
     * Get items ordered by this user.
     * 
     * @return ???
     */
    public function items()
    {
        // What to do here?
    }

I will need to add a new method to the Item model:
    /**
     * Get users that ordered this item.
     * 
     * @return ???
     */
    public function users()
    {
        // What to do here?
    }

Since the default HasManyThrough relationship requires a different table structure, and I cannot modify the existing table structure, it's not applicable here.
As one of possible solutions I'm considering to use staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep, creating a new intermediate table named order_item to map orders to items, and use the following code, for example, for the items method:
    /**
     * Get items ordered by this user.
     * 
     * @return ???
     */
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(
                    Item::class,
                    [Order::class, 'order_item']
            );
    }

If there exists a Laravel solution without external libraries, or you know something more efficient, please share that to me. I'm eager to know the best practice for that case.

try to use the relationship in user model $this->hasManyThrough(Downloadable::class, Order::class, 'client_id', 'id', 'id', 'item_id')

That's not a hasManyThrough, it's a belongsToMany, or a many-to-many relationship; your orders table is a pivot table between users and items, so your'd use public function items() { return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, ...); } in your User class, and public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, ...); } in your Item class. If you want a real orders table, you'd have to move item_id and order_id to a separate pivot, then User -> hasMany Orders -> belongsToMany Items, which is a more typical approach to Users, Orders and Products/Items.

The relationship you have defined is a belongsToMany relationship, but if you're set on using hasManyThrough, purely to retrieve the other set you could use:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get all items ordered by the user.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough
     */
    public function items(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Item::class, Order::class, 'client_id', 'id', 'id', 'item_id');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Get all users who ordered this item.
     * 
     * @return Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough
     */
    public function users(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Order::class, 'item_id', 'id', 'id', 'client_id');
    }
}

However if you are look to create Orders through the relationship you should use the belongsToMany
